# Gradle syntax in Eclipse - fix indentation

Tags: eclipse, groovy, gradle

I installed Gradle Integration for Eclipse, Groovy and other Gradle-related plugins from Eclipse Market place, but I cannot get Eclipse to detect .gradle files.

I need this to format (indentation, tabs, etc.) the file in Eclipse. Is there an alternative other than trying on [IntelliJ IDEA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IntelliJ_IDEA)?